# RecyclerView: Are there alternative of OnItemActivatedListener options for handling an item clicking?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using the new `SelectionTracker` tool (AndroidX version: 1.1.0-alpha01) to support an items selection in `RecyclerView`. I know that with the help of `OnItemActivatedListener` I can handle an item click in order to, for example, open it.

But there is a problem: it doesn't work if there are additional buttons in the item (pause button, menu, etc.). Their click event simply catched with the `OnItemActivatedListener` and I can't recognize if the pause button was pressed or the item was pressed.

As a workaround, I can use (X, Y) coords from `MotionEvent` to determine which element was clicked, but this method looks ugly. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: why not use your own `interface` with adapter `ViewHolder.onClickListener`

Comment: Unfortunately in version 1.1.0-alpha01 `onClickListener` works in a strange way: it handle clicks in select mode and when I select an item it opens spontaneously. So I can't use `onClickListener`

Comment: well i haven't used `1.1.0-alpha01`, i am using `27.1.1` and it works fine

Comment: I also ran into a problem with `onClickListener`, my work around was to check `if (!selectionTracker.hasSelection())` inside the click listener before handling the event. Seems to work fine and fixes the issue without having to use `OnItemActivatedListener` and determining if a child view was clicked.

Comment: @proninyaroslav In the meantime, is there an elegant and performant solution to handle clicks on buttons within a `RecyclerView` item when using the `SelectionTracker`?

Comment: @ThomasVogel As far as I remember they fixed it in new releases

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener